# Can Sendmail Mail Server Listen on Multiple Ports?

Tags: email, sendmail, port, listener

Currently I have a dedicated mail-relay PS that I need to listen on multiple ports, 25 and 80. I know 80 is http, but because of the applications this is being used for it needs to be able to use port 80 to send emails as well.

Can this be done via Webmin? Sorry for my poor understanding of Sendmail Mail Server, but this is the first time I've seen or used it.

The mail-relay server is setup with a white list to only accept emails from certain IPs. Basically, I have a company locked behind a firewall that needs to send out emails via a program on that computer daily and all ports but 80 are locked.

```
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
```

I've tried adding addition lines and I broke the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know whether it can be done via webmin, but you can do this by using the [DAEMON_OPTIONS](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) macro in the *sendmail.mc* file. I am certain that webming allows you to edit *sendmail.mc* and the it will generate the correct *sendmail.cf* and restart sendmail.

**EDIT:** Try:

```
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-80, Port=80')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
```

Comment: I'm worried that I'd do more damage than good in there.

Comment: Keep a backup of the file and then try.

Comment: I broke it and restored it. 
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl

Mean anything to you?

Comment: Those lines enable ipV6 for sendmail

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @kls: Yes. He can omit the Family=inet6 declaration completely.

Answer (score 2):

Check out DaemonPortOptions.

Previously, sendmail would only listen on one port. Needed to run multiple sendmail daemons to list to multiple ports. Now one daemon can listen on multiple ports on multiple interfaces.

http://www.sendmail.org/~gshapiro/8.10.Training/DaemonPortOptions.html

Make sure you have a current enough sendmail version